# react-router-dom. Return blank page after refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## My codes

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
        <Route path="/dashboard/search" component={Search} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import MenuBar from "../../components/MenuBar";
import Search from '../search';

export default function Dashboard() {

  return (
      <Positioner>
        <MenuBar />
        <Content>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard/search" component={Search} />
          </Switch>
        </Content>
      </Positioner>
  );
}
```

`MenuBar` component moves url to the Link(react-router-dom)

## The problem

When I clicked menubar, the url is changed and return component. But when I refresh browser, there is nothing.

```js
<Route path="/dashboard/search" component={Search} />
```

I know that if I add this code to App.js, it will show up on the page even after refresh.

But I want to handle this inside Dashboard.js

### Before refresh

[image]

### After refresh

[image]

I have no idea how to solve it.
Can you give me something to reference or give me answer?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cartwright-w9jx1?file=/App.js

This is codesandbox that simply expresses my problem.
Hope this helps you understand the problem.

When I refresh from `/dashboard/a` url, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:nameComponent?"  component={Dashboard}/> 
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

or try to have a default router

```
<Route path="*" component={Notfound}/>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cartwright-w9jx1?file=/App.js

This is codesandbox that simply expresses my problem.
Hope this helps you understand the problem.

When I refresh from `/dashboard/a` url, nothing comes up.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-meadow-yi9v8?file=/App.js Edited import & edit <Route path="/dashboard/:nameComponent?"  component={Dashboard}/>.  It works.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have configured the default route to the login page
check what are you doing on the login component page.

and also noticed from the screenshot that the route is dashboards/flanets, but I don't see that URL in the routes.

1. see if you are adding any code which will hide the component if login is done .?
2. What are you doing after login redirects some other page .?
3. if you are redirecting add a route for that page as well
4. you can add  and see if that is showing some**Component.

the empty page may be shown if you don't have a router configured for the route

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cartwright-w9jx1?file=/App.js

This is codesandbox that simply expresses my problem.
Hope this helps you understand the problem.

When I refresh from `/dashboard/a` url, nothing comes up.

Comment: Cool, when you click on "A" link, if you are observing the URL is changed to 
https://w9jx1.csb.app/dashboard/a

now the URL pattern is /dashboard/***

when you refresh the page, this pattern is not matching in the routes, you need to have a dynamic router or mention  /dashboard/a in routes

Answer (score 0):

## App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/search" component={Search} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### answer

Deleting `exact` is work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).